# arp table doesn't show entry for macvlan interface after recent ping

Tags: linux, linux-networking, arp

Using Dedicated server.

Main IP on eth0: 88.99.102.103

Default route: 88.99.102.65

Additional IP: 88.99.102.116 has MAC: 00:50:56:00:C4:6E

Creating macvlan interface:

```
ip link add link eth0 mac0 type macvlan
ip addr add 88.99.102.116 dev mac0
ip link set dev mac0 up
```

After ping to 88.99.102.116, why doesn't arp table have entry for 88.99.102.116 IP?

```
# arp -n
Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface
88.99.102.65             ether   2c:21:31:28:a3:19   C                     eth0
```

Comment: I'm definitely no expert but maybe your tables just need updating.  Do a gratuitous ARP.

Comment: have a try: https://serverfault.com/questions/820306/physical-interface-mac-rather-than-macvlan-mac-is-sent-as-arp-response